# Google tag manager single page application window load and history change

Tags: single-page-application, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to create page view tags. I have to create two for two different triggers.

Page view triggered by history change; 
Page view triggered on window load (because first page load doesn't have any history change)

My problem is the home page, which is firing both tags.

Because if put in URL www.mysite.com, the page redirects to my.site.com/home
which creates a window load and a history change. So two page view tags are fired.

I can't exclude historychange trigger to exclude page path: /home because once people got into the site they'll navigate back and forth.

I can't exclude windowload because people may use either URL to enter the site (mysite.com or mystie.com/home)

Anyone can help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to create 1 page view tag instead of 2 and use both triggers. Multiple triggers in GTM tag work with `OR` operator. And set tag to fire once per page.

*Advanced settings -> Tag firing options -> Once per page*

UPD I'm afraid that in this case other hits for virtual pages triggered by `History change` will not be fired (because of 1 per page rule). Try to check what value have variable `Old History Change` after redirection. If `undefined` or empty, you can use it in trigger of `History Change` tag as exclusion.